# Finding a data file in Cython

Tags: python, cython, distutils

I'm writing a cython extension which needs to load a data file at module init. The datafile is installed in the same folder as the .so file via the package_data argument in my setup.py script, but I can't figure out how to find the path to the file.

Specifically, the `__file__` variable isn't set at module import time, and I don't know any other way to determine the where data has been installed. I *can* distribute the module with a `__init__.py` file which calls a function to load the data on import since the `__file__` attribute is correctly set at the point when that code executes, but this seems horribly inelegant, especially since I don't otherwise need any pure python modules.

Is there a simpler solution?

What's the best practice for distributing a cython extension with data files?

Comment: Have you tried [`pkgutil.get_data()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.get_data)?

Comment: Ahh! Thank you! I wasn't aware of pkgutil. That works perfectly.